# Two Angular directive that are very similar, how can I share the code?

Tags: angularjs, angular2-directives

I have two custom date picking directives

**One for a single day
One for selecting a range**

About 50% of the code in each is duplicate code(mostly populating the month with days and selecting a single day), if not very similar. I am trying to stay as DRY as I can, but having issues figuring out how to approach this.

**Option 1**
My initial thought is to have a calendar service that can hold some of the shared functions that can then be used in either directive? Is this considered bad convention?

**Option 2**
Otherwise I thought of having a calendar E directive with all the html/initial values such as the days in the given month and the ability to change months. Then create two A directives, on for each that carries on the functionality?

**Options 3**
?????

I feel I can hash out option 1 quickly, and it will work. Option 2 sounds like a more elegant solution to me, I'd rather write some sexy elegant code(which seems kind of stupid.) - But in the end I would prefer to take the best approach.

Option 3, I'm all ears if you have other ideas

Comment: You could pass a value into the directive that is for a single day or range, that way it's the same directive but switch the logic. Option one is certainly not a bad convention, though. In fact it is probably the main advantage of a service

Comment: how similar is the ui? if it's similar enough, you can do one of to things. 1) use the directive for the single date selection in the range selection (if I understand correctly, the range is basically 2 single date selections). 2) create a single directive that receives a flag that indicates whether it's a single selection or a range and put that flag in an ng-if. I would recommend the first option but that depends on the difference between their ui, if it's 2 of the same thing (and then use the first option) or is it an extra element (and then use the second one)

Comment: Very similar for now - this could change however, not drastically, but enough where the html structure would differ on how the month and year selector looks.

So since they have the potential/flexibility to be different, option 1 should be the way to go I take is what you're saying

Answer (score 1):

I think the best approach is to use `Services` for the shared logic.

And for the directive behavior you should use nested directives.

Answer (score 1):

Best approach here would be to isolate that 50% code (or as much as you can) and put it into a service or factory. Personally I prefer Services.

```
app.service("ServiceName", function(injectors, ...)
{
   // code
})
```

Then setup your directives to use controllers (not link), and inject that service into the controllers:

```
...
controller: function($scope, ServiceName, $otherInjectors ...)
{
  // call your ServiceName.methods() as needed
}
...
```

Another option is to use angular.extend on an existing controller, but I think that's likely overkill for what you're looking to do... which is basically simplify your 2 nearly identical directives into basic logic (service) and then UI-specific stuff in the individual controllers.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Yea, already using controllers rather than link, so I feel I've slowly been giving myself an alley-oop for this approach :) 

Think this is the approach I'll go with for now - it's familiar and makes the most sense. Cheers